# SortBy in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I have such function show:

```
public function show($post)
{
    $post = Post::whereId($post)->filter(\Request::only(['fields']))->firstOrFail();

    return Response::json($post);
}
```

How do I add in this function sortBy('some field from the table which I sent')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
    $post = Post::whereId($post)->filter(\Request::only(['fields']))->orderBy('desired_field','ASC')->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Method not found. What i must include?

Comment: Oh didn't notice about the `firstOrFail`. Using this method will give you a Model instance instead of Collection so you have to make an `order by` with SQL. Let me  update my answer

Comment: Now i get such result as without sorting.
P.S.  I edit 'desired_field' to param I need.

Comment: Check your query results by replacing `->firstOrFail()` with `->get()` and doing `dd($posts)` so you can see all the results. It doesnt throw error?

Comment: Anywhere I see the result without sorting

Comment: Which type is the ordering field?

Comment: count_recipe_link_redirect - integer

Comment: Is the query working when you execute it manually on database server?

Comment: yes, but when i try use this function i have a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152154/discussion-between-georg-and-aaron0207).